# How do I tell grunt server to use a different html file?

Tags: gruntjs

This should be obvious but I can't find it in the grunt help or web site.

How do I tell

```
grunt server
```

to use some file other than index.html?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean exactly?

`grunt server` serves all files in your directory how any static file server would.

So lets say you have files called `index.html`and `contact.html` in your directory. Now those files get served up at whichever port you configured on localhost.

So by visiting `localhost:PORT/index.html` and `localhost:PORT/contact.html` you can see those pages in your browser.

Comment: By default it serves index.html.  I'm trying to change the default.  Java web servers usually have a list of welcome files.  Where does grunt set its default?

Comment: I don't know that there is a way to set a different file as a default.